# CSS margin does not work when content height too large

Tags: css

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/octref/q47HX/2/).
Code:

```
<body>
    <div id="all">
        <p>just testing</br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
            just testing
        </p>
    </div>
</body>

html, body {
    height : 100%;
}
#all {
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    min-height: 95%;
}
```

What I would like to achieve is:
Suppose h is the full screen height.
`h x 5%` margin on the top.
`h x 90%` content.
`h x 5%` margin on the bottom.
If the content is more than one page, I just want to keep the margins and let the content grow on height.

If I delete all the `</br>`s in my `<p>` tag, then it works.
However, if I have content more than 1 page, then the bottom margin disappear.
So how should I do this?

By the way, the 95% min-height in css, to my surprise, is right. (Not 90%). MDN and W3School seem to be suggesting that height doesn't include margin/padding/border.

Comment: I'm seeing there margin on both top and bottom in your fiddle.

Comment: @C-Link Hack, when I open it in Firefox I see the margin too! But sadly it doesn't work in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a div under the content.

```
<body>
    <div id="all">
      <p>
        There is a lot of content here.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div style="height:1px"></div>
<body>
```

Here's the demo http://jsfiddle.net/jeZmR/

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the CSS for the html and body tags as they aren't needed. All you would need is the CSS for #all

```
#all {
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    min-height: 95%;
}
```

You can see it working here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SsA6H/2/).

Comment: But is adding margin/padding as 0 globally a correct thing to do?

Comment: It's not needed, I accidentally added it by habit. I updated the JSFiddle example

Comment: But another problem is, when the content is less than one page, the div doesn't fill 90%. So the html and body are needed.